# How to Retrieve the shared link of a file Programmatically

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, office-365

I am using C# to programmatically access files on our Office 365 SharePoint site using the `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.dll`. In one of our shared folders all the documents are `Shared with anyone with a link` (i.e. `https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=QRsbIP0XzXC9%2bONJWf8tqXCTmIUq2n04JArVh%2bm1dnw%3d&docid=02fecf600149d41fc85b13fca96af9467`  Is it possible to retrieve this link programmatically?  I can get the URL of the file without a problem but need the URL of the shared link.

My code so far:

```
//using our client context, load the folder of the files we want links to
Folder folder = Program.spConnection.context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(Properties.Settings.Default.SPImages);

FileCollection filec = folder.Files;
Program.spConnection.context.Load(filec);
Program.spConnection.context.ExecuteQuery();

List<string> allSharedURLs = new List<string>();
//Load Each File in the folder
foreach (File f in filec)
{
    Program.spConnection.context.Load(f);
    Program.spConnection.context.ExecuteQuery();

    // I would like to add the publically shared url to the list at this point
    // allSharedURLs.Add( theLink );    
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the user who you are Sharing File is part of SharePoint then you can simply pass the URL to the user, who can access the file directly.

For external users, you can get this link using `ObjectSharingInformation` [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.objectsharinginformation_properties.aspx). This class has property `AnonymousEditLink` and `AnonymousViewLink`

You can use below snippet for that

```
var item = //code to get list item..
var objSharingInfo = ObjectSharingInformation.GetObjectSharingInformation(
        clientContext, item, false, true, false, true, true, true, true);
clientContext.Load(sharingInfo);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
//objSharingInfo.AnonymousEditLink 
//objSharingInfo.AnonymousViewLink
```

Comment: Hi @Amal Hashim! I get "ObjectSharingInformation is not defined" every time. Does it work for You in Sp Online in 2018?